# Extjs 4 grid: place icon in cell according to store text value

Tags: javascript, grid, extjs4

I have a store with a field that has either "Y" or "N" in it. I would like to take that Y or N value and place a little green or red icon in the grid instead of the text. I have been messing around with a conditional rendering function but I can't figure out how to get an icon to appear according to the value. So far I have

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.columns=[
        {header: 'PreReq', dataIndex: 'PreReq', width: 50,
            renderer: function(value){
                if(value == 'Y'){
                    //some code to put green icon in this cell
                }
                else if(value =='N'){
                    //come code to put red icon in this cell
                }
                else{
                    //some code to put error icon in this cell
                }
            }
        }
    ];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is as easy as:

```
return '<img src="..." />';
```

Or if you prefer the css way, you can do:

```
renderer: function( value, metadata, record )
{
    metadata.tdCls = 'yes-icon'
}
```

Comment: Or you can use `metaData.tdClass` if you rather do it css way.

Comment: Think a single complete answer is better than two - so I merged it with yours.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I think its almost working, all I'm getting is a broken image logo though. I triple checked the path and I'm sure its fine. Does it matter if its a .gif?

Comment: @alex9311: nope. If image is not shown - then either binary file is broken or path is invalid. Check what actual path is requested using chrome dev tools or firebug

Comment: I'm pretty sure the path is relative to the index file if you're using `<img>`.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize I had to set the path from the application directory and not from the application/app/view/user/ where the .js file was. Many thanks!